# Database & Structure for SaaS reporting software

Tags: database-design, schema, application-design

I'm building a SaaS application to allow users to upload data and perform reporting and analytics on it. The reporting and analytics would be quite simple like grouping and aggregating. This has presented some interesting problems.

1. I would expect to have multiple users. Initially a few hundred, but scaling upwards to thousands (if lucky of course).
2. Each user uploads multiple tables of data to analyze. I do not know the schema before hand and do not have control over number of rows, columns, or tables. This would all have to be created dynamically.
3. I'd expect that this should be horizontally scalable as well?
4. Each time a user registers on our site they'd be able to upload a CSV file along with a structure that they'd like to analyse.

I am not very experienced in databases, but these are the options I've considered:

1. Create a MySQL/PostgreSQL Database and create a new table each time someone wants a table. However I am concerned about the scalability of this approach. Plus I'd have to change schema each time.
2. Use a NoSQL database which I'm not too familiar with but am willing to learn. Don't know how I'd keep multiple different tables.

Comment: Why you need table each time, How you are looking to design you Database?

Comment: @vijayp - Each time a user registers on our site they'd be able to upload a CSV file along with a structure that they'd like to analyse and query.

Comment: Well, I see some complication in runtime with creating table like data type for columns, alter table/Indexes and then fetching data from table, Why not to save the file in server, and save file path in Database.

Comment: I have read numerous times about loading unstructured data into PostgreSql. Are you using Amazon Redshift? If not, you should definitely check it out.